# Explanation about QStateMachine delay function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer, qstatemachine

I used this function in my program:

```
void delay(QState * state1, int millisecond, QAbstractState * state2) 
{
   auto timer = new QTimer(state1);
   timer->setSingleShot(true);
   timer->setInterval(millisecond);

   QObject::connect(state1, &QState::entered, timer, static_cast<void (QTimer::*)()>(&QTimer::start));
   QObject::connect(state1, &QState::exited,  timer, &QTimer::stop);

   state1 -> addTransition(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), state2);
}
```

I made a copy-paste from an example and I did not understand this part of code:

```
QObject::connect(state1,..., static_cast<void (QTimer::*)()>(&QTimer::start));
```

Anyone can explain to me what this code is ? How it works in the program ?

PS. I tried to change that code with this but it didn't work:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(state1);
.
.  //same code as before
.
QObject::connect(stato1,&QState::entered,timer,[&] {timer->start();} );
QObject::connect(stato1,&QState::exited, timer,[&] {timer->stop(); } );

stato1 -> addTransition(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),stato2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two [`QTimer::start` slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#public-slots), one without parameters and one with `int msec` parameter. To connect to the correct one with the new connect syntax, you must specify the slot type with a `static_cast`.

So in this line:

```
QObject::connect(state1, &QState::entered, timer, static_cast<void (QTimer::*)()>(&QTimer::start));
```

You connect to `QTimer::start` slot which takes no arguments.

If you had a signal with an `int` parameter and you wanted to connect to `QTimer::start(int msec)` slot, you'd do it like this:

```
connect(this, &MyClass::mySignal, timer, static_cast<void (QTimer::*)(int)>(&QTimer::start));
```

You can read more about using overloaded signals/slots with the new connect syntax [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Open_Questions).

You can also use [`qOverload`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtglobal.html#qOverload) to remove the need of the ugly `static_cast`.

In the snippet where you use lambda expressions, you capture `timer` by reference. You should capture it by value instead:

```
QObject::connect(stato1, &QState::entered, timer, [=]{timer->start();});
```

Comment: +1 that is interesting... in this case would you think it's better to use the old  system for clarity/ease of use: `connect(state1, SIGNAL(entered(int)), timer, SLOT(start(int)));`?

Comment: @code_fodder That is what I tend to do. The old syntax is much easier to read and write when dealing with overloaded signals/slots.

Comment: @thuga, perhaps, but I believe it is worth paying the price of the more complex syntax, for the benefit of compile time checks. Note however, that in Qt 5.7 we can get the best of both worlds, where helper functions were added to abstract away the complex syntax. For e.g. QOverload<int>::of(&QTimer:start)

Comment: @ManuelH Cool, didn't know about `QOverload`.